# Win -> OSX Python Portability: symlink for "C:\\" on Mac to redirect i/o to UNIX filepath?

Tags: python, windows, macos, filepath, portability

**Context:** Our company has a suite of testing software that wasn't designed to be os-portable (i.e. it was only designed to work on Windows).  Recently we've been trying to set up the testing suite and environment on my Mavericks-running Macbook Air, but again and again we're running into issues of a program looking for a file in a windows-only filepath like: `C:\\folder1\\file.txt`.

**Solution:** Now of course the obvious way to solve this is to use `sys.platform` to figure out what OS the program is running on, and then choose a corresponding filepath (if statements).  But I was wondeirng if it's possible for me to set up some kind of symbolic link on my Mac, so that when the Python program looks for `C:\\folder1\\file.txt`, the OS will redirect it towards `~/folder1/file.txt`, the corresponding UNIX filepath.

Is this possible?  If so it would be a much faster solution then going through every file i/o in the suite and adding in if statements and UNIX friendly filepath alternatives.

Comment: it's a windows .exe? you can't run that in osx... or you're taking the source of this thing and compiling it to a mac executable? if that's the case, then you should rewrite the code to be portable, instead of trying to band-aid over the problem with another layer of potentially buggy translation.

Comment: @MarcB The question says that the code is running and says that it's Python. Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: Ah yes, burying that little factoid deep in the question, instead of adding it as a tag in the first place.